# PyXero Library Validation Exception

Tags: python, xero-api

I'm trying to add a payment to xero using the pyxero python library for python3.
I'm able to add invoices and contacts, but payments always returns a validation exception.
Here is the data I'm submitting:

```
payments.put([{'Amount': '20.00', 
               'Date': datetime.date(2016, 5, 25), 
               'AccountCode': 'abc123', 
               'Reference': '8831_5213', 
               'InvoiceID': '09ff0465-d1b0-4fb3-9e2e-3db4e83bb240'}])
```

And the xero response:

```
xero.exceptions.XeroBadRequest: ValidationException: A validation exception occurred
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note: this solution became a hack inside pyxero to get the result I needed. This may not be the best solution for you.

The XML that pyxero generates for "payments.put" does not match the "[PUT Payments](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/payments/)" XML structure found in the xero documentation.

I first changed the structure of your dictionary so that the XML generated in [basemanager.py](https://github.com/freakboy3742/pyxero/blob/master/xero/basemanager.py) was similar to the documentation's.

```
data = {
    'Invoice': {'InvoiceID': "09ff0465-d1b0-4fb3-9e2e-3db4e83bb240"},
    'Account': {"AccountID": "58F8AD72-1F2E-AFA2-416C-8F660DDD661B"},
    'Date': datetime.datetime.now(),
    'Amount': 30.00,
}
xero.payments.put(data)
```

The error still persisted though, so I was forced to start changing code inside pyxero's **basemanager.py**.

In **basemanager.py** on line 133, change the formatting of the date:

```
val = sub_data.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

to:

```
val = sub_data.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

pyxero is originally returning the Time. This is supposed to only be a Date value - The docs stipulate the formatting.

Then, again in **basemanager.py**, on line 257, change the following:

```
body = {'xml': self._prepare_data_for_save(data)}
```

to:

```
if self.name == "Payments":
    body = {'xml': "<Payments>%s</Payments>" % self._prepare_data_for_save(data)}
else:
    body = {'xml': self._prepare_data_for_save(data)}
```

Please note that in order for you to be able to create a payment in the first place, the Invoice's "Status" must be set to "AUTHORISED".
Also, make sure the Payment's "Amount" is no greater than Invoice's "AmountDue" value.